# AutoLayout positioning problems in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

My problem is on rotation (rotate left/rotate right), the `UIImageView` that I have created touching the bottom of the screen (which also has 2 buttons within it) disappears. I did a search in Stack Overflow and other online forums and I haven't been able to address this problem at all.

I have checked the "Use Auto Layout" option as well. I tried specifying various alignment constraints but to no avail. All I want is the `UIImageView` to be visible (along with the 2 buttons within it) when I rotate the device left/right. Xcode version 5.1.1, emulator type iPhone Retina (4-inch). Kindly let me know if you need any further information. Appreciate some help!

Comment: What is the frame of the UIImageView before and after rotation?

Comment: You're putting buttons inside an UIImageView? That's a mistake in itself.

Comment: Hi skladek, in the normal viewing window the frame dimensions are 160(x), 553(y), 320(width) & 30(height). I am not sure how to check after rotation as the display disappears.

Hi mattyohe, why would it not be ok to have buttons within an UIImageView? I need to have an image as a button and that is my reason for using an imageView.

Comment: Then why don't you set an image in UIButton?

Comment: `myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` Did you do that? Its `NO` by default. If you did it programmatically, share some code? There could be multiple possibilities for this errata.

Comment: thank you very much for all your thoughts. Appreciated. I have set userinteractionenabled = yes but it has no effect. Currently, I am able to get this:
---------
Successfully able to create a button as an clickable image icon at the bottom left corner of the phone screen.

I need this:
------------
Need to create a button as an clickable image icon at the bottom left corner of the phone screen which stays in the same position when the screen is rotated.

If theres any sample code, can u pls share them

Comment: Can you provide the constraints that you have specified for the image view? Without looking at them, I might guess that you are telling the image view to position itself based on how far it is from the *top* of the screen, when you need it to position itself relative to the *bottom* of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this image help or you need further explanation?

[image]

I added a button and specified a fixed width (200), as well as a leading and bottom space of 10 to its superview. That means that this button will always be at the bottom left corner.

Comment: Sharing what I did to solve my problem.
1. Add a toolbar from the object library to the bottom of the screen
2. Add a flexible space bar button item
3. Add a button item to the extreme left and extreme right and use an image instead of text
4. In order to make sure, the dimensions and icon are visible on rotation, select the toolbar and click the "pin" menu in the storyboard. In there, select the two horizontal arrows and the vertical arrow at the bottom and click add 3 constraints. This fixed my problem!